# Python - How to search for two strings in text file and export them to text file?

Tags: python

I want to check text file if it contains strings Text2 and Text3. If it does, export to other file in format text,text. I tried many things but can only find one line correct..

Text file:

```
 Text1: text
 Text2: text
 Text3: text
 Text4: text
 Date: date
 --------------------------
 Text1: text
 Text2: text
 Text3: text
 Text4: text
 Date: date
 --------------------------

 Text1: text
 Text2: text
 Text3: text
 Text4: text
 Date: date
 --------------------------
 ...
```

Comment: Judging from your example, there are multiple occurrences of `Text2` and `Text3` in your file. Do they always come in pairs? If so, does `Text2` always precede `Text3`?

Comment: Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4 always the same, only text change after :

Comment: Give an example of what you want as an output of the given input. It's very confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f1, open("output.txt", "w") as f2:
    for line in f1:
        if line.startswith('Text2'):
           t2 = line.rstrip().replace('Text2: ', '')
        elif line.startswith('Text3'):
           t3 = line.rstrip().replace('Text3: ', '') 
           f2.write('{},{}\n'.format(t2, t3))
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank You very much!